# Numpy array function returns inconsistent shapes

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to define a simple function `ddf()` that outputs the Hessian matrix of a particular mathematical function, given a 2D vector, `x` as the input :

```
import numpy as np

def ddf(x):
    dd11 = 2*x[1]+8
    dd12 = 2*x[0]-8*x[1]-8
    dd21 = 2*x[0]-8*x[1]-8
    dd22 = -8*x[0]+2
   return np.array([[dd11, dd12], [dd21, dd22]])

x0 = np.zeros((2,1))
G = ddf(x0)
print(G)
```

I expect the output to be a 2x2 square array/matrix, however it yields what appears to be a 4x1 column instead.
Stranger still, using

```
G.shape
```

yields (2L, 2L, 1L), not (2L,2L) as expected.
My objective is to obtain G in 2x2 form. Can anyone assist? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to python, but I think that will work:

```
...
G = ddf(x0)  
G = np.reshape(G, (2,2))  
print(G)
```

It yields a (2,2) as you wanted.

Comment: It does indeed, thank you very much. I also found that reshaping the 2x1 vector (x)  as a 1x2 vector does the job

Answer (score 1):

Your input to the function `ddf()` is a 2x1 matrix, meaning all of x[0] and x[1] are vectors not scalers(floats or ints). So each element of your output matrix are 1-sized vectors, as all operations in numpy are applied elements wise if arrays are passed to the functions. 
Couple of things, you can do :

- It seems that you expect x[0], x[1] to be scalars, so change the input to shape (2,) in `x0 = np.zeros((2,))`.
- Or reshape the output as `G.reshape((2,2))` to remove the extra dimension.